# How to retrieve buildings polygon in Google Places near a given latitude longitude

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

Given a latitude and longitude, google places api can be used to query for nearby places. But it seems to give only places marked as dots on the google map. I am interested in retrieving the buildings which are marked as grey polygons on google maps.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Places API does not currently support this feature. If you believe this would be a useful feature you can submit a 'Places API - Feature Request' here: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Feature%20Request

You could however in the mean time use a Rectangle or Circle overlay from the Google Maps API with an estimated building size at the Latitude and Longitude provided by the Places API.
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#BasicShapes